# Replace string pattern in a data frame

Tags: regex, dataframe, dictionary, replace

suppose I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Aruba', 'lorem Andorra ipsum', 'Afgahnistan', 'Bla Yemen, Rep.', 'South Africa'],
 'Geographic region': ['Latin America and Caribbean', 'Europe and Central Asia', 'South Asia', 'Middle East and North Africa', 'Sub Saharan Africa']})
```

How can I replace all cells which include the pattern *Yemen* with the string *Yemen*?
The result should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Aruba', 'lorem Andorra ipsum', 'Afgahnistan', 'Yemen', 'South Africa'],
 'Geographic region': ['Latin America and Caribbean', 'Europe and Central Asia', 'South Asia', 'Middle East and North Africa', 'Sub Saharan Africa']})
```

In the next step, is it possible to replace all cells including *Andorra* with *Andorra* and all cells including *Yemen* with *Yemen* in one step, using lists or dictionaries?

The result should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Aruba', 'Andorra', 'Afgahnistan', 'Yemen', 'South Africa'],
 'Geographic region': ['Latin America and Caribbean', 'Europe and Central Asia', 'South Asia', 'Middle East and North Africa', 'Sub Saharan Africa']})
```

I tried for example

```
df.replace(regex='lorem Andorra ipsum', value='Andorra ')
```

which works for sure, since it looks for *lorem Andorra ipsum*. But that is a too specific approach. I further tried different reg expressions as

```
df.replace(regex=r'^Andorra.$', value='Andorra'). But it didn't work.
```

I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Maybe just `df['Country'][df['Country'].str.contains(r"\bYemen\b", case=False)] = 'Yemen'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this approach if the number of words is not too huge:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Aruba', 'lorem Andorra ipsum', 'Afgahnistan', 'Bla Yemen, Rep.', 'South Africa'],
 'Geographic region': ['Latin America and Caribbean', 'Europe and Central Asia', 'South Asia', 'Middle East and North Africa', 'Sub Saharan Africa']})
l = ['Yemen', 'Andorra']
>>> df['Country'].str.replace(fr"(?s).*?\b({'|'.join(sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True))})\b.*", r"\1")
0           Aruba
1         Andorra
2     Afgahnistan
3           Yemen
4    South Africa
Name: Country, dtype: object
```

The `fr"(?s).*?\b({'|'.join(sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True))})\b.*` code creates a regex using the `l` list strings as alternation in the capturing group (with ID 1) and looks like

```py
(?s).*?\b(Andorra|Yemen)\b.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KnpRFr/1). Note the longer country names will be put first, so as to match the longest country name from country names sharing the same prefix.

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - a `re.DOTALL` inline modifier, makes `.` match line break chars, too
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(Andorra|Yemen)` - either `Andorra` or `Yemen` string
- `\b` - word boundary
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and especially the regex explanation. They help a lot! Also on different exercises!

Answer (score 3):

first of all, put all patterns in a single array
then loop this array, on top of another loop that is looping in the df, to search for the pattern and replace.

Here is a code:

```
patterns = ["Yemen","Andorra"]
for pattern in patterns: 
  for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row[0].lower().find(pattern.lower()) != -1 :  
        df['Country'][index] = pattern
        break
print(df)
```

And the reult:

```
        Country             Geographic region
0         Aruba   Latin America and Caribbean
1       Andorra       Europe and Central Asia
2   Afgahnistan                    South Asia
3         Yemen  Middle East and North Africa
4  South Africa            Sub Saharan Africa
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It works perfectly and is quite a straight forward solution and easy to understand!